# How to change value dynamically for html elment?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load initial params dummy data on UI when page loads so I can customize with real data so in below code memberid when I change on UI and send with request it is always taking memberid that was initially loaded to the page, any idea what is wrong with the code ?

main.html

```js
  <script>
            var initialParams = [{
                "memberid": "etyhdjhsYYhajdsjdsQ==",
                "prescriptionInfo": [{
                    "dispensingStoreDetails": {
                        "dispensingStoreNumber": "2921",
                        "dispensingStoreNPINumber": "1043382302",
                        "dispensingStorePharmacyName": "PROCARE PHARMACY DIRECT, L.L.C.",
                        "dispensingStoreType": "SPECIALTY_PHARMACY",
                        "dispensingStoreCity": "MONROEVILLE"
                    }
                }]
            
            }]
            $('#spltyRxDetails').val(JSON.stringify(initialParams, undefined, 4));
            var specialtyRequest = {
                "lineOfBusiness": "SPECIALTY",
                "rxOrder": {
                    "prescriptionDetails": []
                }
            }
             var requestParam = {orders: []};
            specialtyRequest.rxOrder.prescriptionDetails = initialParams;
            requestParam.orders = specialtyRequest;
    
    </script>
```

```html
    <form>
        <div class="form-group memberInfo">
            <label for="client_id">Client Id</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_id" placeholder="Enter a Client Id">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="spltyParams" style="border:1px solid rgb(242, 255, 0)">
                <label for="spltyRxDetails">validate Order - Request Parameters</label>
                <!--<div class="col-lg-12">-->
                    <!--<label for="spltymemberidEnc">Specialty member idEnc (Encrypted Specialty ID)</label>-->
                    <!--<input type="text" name="spltymemberidEnc" id="spltymemberidEnc"/>-->
                <!--</div>-->
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control text-area-request" id="spltyRxDetails" placeholder="Enter Validate Order - Request Parameters in JSON"></textarea>
            </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="execWrapperApi()">Submit</button>
                &nbsp;<label id="status"></label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you using AJAX to submit the form? show the `execWrapperApi()` function.

Comment: @Barmar that is global function using $.AJAX

Comment: The problem is probably in that function, so show it.

Comment: @Barmar that function passing request as it is no manipulation there

Comment: The textarea won't go back to the original value by itself. So something must be happening there to reset it. Just show us the function so we can see for ourselves.