# How to change text area value after initialization?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I have a case scenario below I created in JSBIN So I have data populated in text area , so once i have dummy data i want to change memberid and rest of the data so i can send request to backend with real data but when i click submit it always take data that was initialize first time onload , any idea how to fix this issue when change data on sumbit it should have new data like memberid that i typed in text area.

main.html

```js
var initialParams = [{
  "memberid": "etyhdjhsYYhajdsjdsQ==",
  "prescriptionInfo": [{
    "dispensingStoreDetails": {
      "dispensingStoreNumber": "1",
      "dispensingStoreNPINumber": "12302"
    }
  }]
}]

function init() {
  document.getElementById("spltyRxDetails").value = JSON.stringify(initialParams);
}
var specialtyRequest = {
  "lineOfBusiness": "SPECIALTY",
  "rxOrder": {
    "prescriptionDetails": []
  }
}
var requestParam = {
  orders: []
};
specialtyRequest.rxOrder.prescriptionDetails = initialParams;
requestParam.orders = specialtyRequest;
window.onload = init;

function execWrapperApi() {
  console.log(requestParam.orders);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group memberInfo">
    <label for="client_id">Client Id</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_id" placeholder="Enter a Client Id">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="spltyParams" style="border:1px solid rgb(242, 255, 0); width:100px; length:100px">
      <label for="spltyRxDetails">validate Order - Request Parameters</label>

      <textarea type="text" class="form-control text-area-request" id="spltyRxDetails" placeholder="Enter Validate Order - Request Parameters in JSON"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="execWrapperApi()">Submit</button> &nbsp;
    <label id="status"></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Assigning to `.value` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Is this different from your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889077/how-to-change-value-dynamically-for-html-elment

Comment: @Barmar its kind of same question i have added little app to understand , would you able to help here values are not changing when i change and submit

Answer (score 0):

Editing the textarea doesn't change the `specialtyRequest` object that you used to initialize it. You need to call `JSON.parse` to convert the text back to an object.

```js
var initialParams = [{
  "memberid": "etyhdjhsYYhajdsjdsQ==",
  "prescriptionInfo": [{
    "dispensingStoreDetails": {
      "dispensingStoreNumber": "1",
      "dispensingStoreNPINumber": "12302"
    }
  }]
}]

function init() {
  document.getElementById("spltyRxDetails").value = JSON.stringify(initialParams);
}
var specialtyRequest = {
  "lineOfBusiness": "SPECIALTY",
  "rxOrder": {
    "prescriptionDetails": []
  }
}
var requestParam = {
  orders: []
};
specialtyRequest.rxOrder.prescriptionDetails = initialParams;
requestParam.orders = specialtyRequest;
window.onload = init;

function execWrapperApi() {
  requestParam.orders = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("spltyRxDetails").value);
  console.log(requestParam.orders);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group memberInfo">
    <label for="client_id">Client Id</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_id" placeholder="Enter a Client Id">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="spltyParams" style="border:1px solid rgb(242, 255, 0); width:100px; length:100px">
      <label for="spltyRxDetails">validate Order - Request Parameters</label>

      <textarea type="text" class="form-control text-area-request" id="spltyRxDetails" placeholder="Enter Validate Order - Request Parameters in JSON"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="execWrapperApi()">Submit</button> &nbsp;
    <label id="status"></label>
  </div>
</form>
```